# Understanding creation and annihilation operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, second-quantization

I have a conceptual question about creation/annihilation operators as I read a textbook. According to the book, suppose we have eigenstates and eigenvalues of the form:

$$
H\phi_\lambda=\epsilon_\lambda\phi_\lambda
$$

The wave function $\Psi(r)$ could be expanded as:
$$
\Psi(r)=\Sigma_\lambda a_\lambda(t)\phi_\lambda(r) 
$$
and
$$
\Psi^\dagger(r)=\Sigma_\lambda a^\dagger_\lambda(t)\phi^*_\lambda(r) 
$$
Where $a$ and $a^\dagger$ are creation and annihilation operator, which follow the usual commutation rules.
It seems like the creation and annihilation operators are the coefficients of the expansion, which is usually complex numbers, rather than some operators that add/remove a particle from a state to me. So I am a little confused. How should I understand them in this case?
One reason I could think of is by calculating $|\Psi|^2$, it does act like the wave function in first quantization. If that's true, is the wave function normalized in this expansion, given that the basis set is already normalized?
And for the reference, the book I was reading is "Many-particle Physics" 3rd by Gerald D. Mahan.

Comment: The $a$ coefficients are likely not creation or destruction operators, but just numbers.  There must be confusion with your source.

Comment: It could be me that got confused. But $a$ and $a^\dagger$ was used to transform the Hamiltonian to its second quantized form in the same section. One thing that I notice is the author refer to them as operators when he starts calling $\Psi(r)$ a field operator. So I guess the two cases are different?

Comment: $\Psi(r)$ is not a wave function, but an operator.

Comment: I see. Thank you both. I guess they depend on the context then.